# Read first childnode of the last element

Tags: asp.net, xml

Im using ASP.NET, C# and XMLDOC for reading an XMl file.
This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<News>
<article>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>ניסוי</title>
    <pics>name.png</pics>
    <header>כותרת משנה ניסיונית</header>
    <text>זוהי הכתבה הראשונה, כרגע היא בניסיון אנחנו נמשיך ונבדוק</text>
</article>
<article>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>נ2יסוי</title>
    <pics>nam2e.png</pics>
    <header>כותרת2 מ2שנה ניסיונית</header>
    <text>זוהי הכתב2ה2 הראשונה, כרגע היא בניסיון אנחנו נמשיך ונבדוק</text>
</article>
</News>
```

I want to read the id node in the last article element.
I tried this code (after loading the xml file):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.DocumentElement.LastChild.ChildNodes.Item(0).Value
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("URL");

var LatestId = doc.Element("News")
               .Elements("article")
               .Select(E => E.Element("id").Value)
               .Max();
```

Alternatively you can use

```
var LatestId = doc.Element("News")
                   .Elements("article")
                   .Last().Element("id").Value;
```

Comment: Thank you but this is the error i get:Error 1 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Projects\פרויקט אתר\App_Code\xml.cs 168 20 D:\Projects\פרויקט אתר\

Comment: The error with go away when you Switch from XmlDocument to XDocument.

Comment: Thanks, didn't noticed that.

Comment: I am getting:sequence contain no element for the file above. any idea why?

Comment: you need to load the document XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("URL"); or XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"FileLocation");

Comment: This is the function:
'code'
string xmlpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/").Replace("admin\\", "");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlpath + "/news.xml");
        return doc.Element("News").Elements("article").Last().Element("id").Value;

Comment: @user2390564 - I dont want to be rude but people are not going to spoonfeed you here. You need to debug and see if the file path you get exists.

Comment: the file path is correct, its the same as others functions that work